# Programatically copy an image from user entity to webform submission entity

Tags: 8, entities, users, files, webforms

Using a custom webform handler, I am trying to copy an image **from** the image field (`field_usr_avatar_img`) located at the user account page **to** the image element (`avatar_img`) located at the webform submission of the a webform where my custom handler is set.

In my custom handler, I have tried the below:

```
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;

public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission) {

$userid = 25;
$userprofile = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($userid);

// Get the image id.
$avatarimg = $userprofile->field_usr_avatar_img->id()

// Set webform submission Data.
$webform_submission->setElementData('avatar_img', $avatarimg);  

// Save the updated webform submission.
$webform_submission->save();

}
```

However, I ended up with below error:

```
Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\file\Plugin\Field\FieldType\FileFieldItemList::id() in Drupal\my_custom_module\Plugin\WebformHandler\customWebformHandler->submitForm() (line 61...
```

Line 61 is: `$avatarimg = $userprofile->field_usr_avatar_img->id()`

any help on how to copy the image from an entity to another ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You must call `->entity` to get the file entity, then you can call `->id()` like this, `$userprofile->field_usr_avatar_img->entity->id()`.